# Number of ways of choosing 4 ice creams from 6 different varieties if each variety is available in unlimited amount:

Tags: combinatorics

> A supermarket offers ice creams in 6 different varieties. Ice creams of each variety are unlimited and identical. In how many ways can you choose 4 ice creams, repetition is allowed but the order doesn't matter.

I know this problem can be solved directly from the method given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets).

But I tried to solve this problem in a different way and ended up getting the wrong answer,

My approach: Number of ways all 4 ice creams are distinct is $\binom{6}{4}$, number of ways two are of the same flavour is $\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{2}$, number of ways three of them are of the same flavour is $\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1}$ and number of ways all of them are of the same flavour is $\binom{6}{1}$, adding them up gives $111$ as the answer which is not correct, can any please tell me where I have gone wrong?

The correct answer to this question is $126$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not consider the case in which you select two ice creams each of two different flavors, which can be done in $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ ways.

Comment: Thank you very much @N. F. Taussig